# C 2D Array changes 2 elements at the same time

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is my 2D array `int myarray[79][24];` Whenever I change an element at row 0, it changes another element row 24 at the same time and vice versa.

For example, `myarray[35][0] = 'X';` changes `myarray[35][0]` and  `myarray[34][24]` to X at the same time. And when I tried `myarray[40][24] = 'X';` it changes `myarray[40][24]` and `myarray[41][0]` at the same time.

It seems like the first and last row are mirroring each other. How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. Show some examples of the input, the expected output, and the actual output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Specification: [6.5.2.1 Array subscripting](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)**

> Successive subscript operators designate an element of a multidimensional array object.
>   If E is an n-dimensional array (n ≥ 2) with dimensions i × j × ... × k, then E (used as
>   other than an lvalue) is converted to a pointer to an (n − 1)-dimensional array with
>   dimensions j × ... × k. If the unary * operator is applied to this pointer explicitly, or
>   implicitly as a result of subscripting, the result is the referenced (n − 1)-dimensional
>   array, which itself is converted into a pointer if used as other than an lvalue. It follows
>   from this that arrays are stored in row-major order (last subscript varies fastest).

C is a language which allows the programmer to do a lot. For example, there is no `IndexOutOfBoundsError`. An array is just a pointer to the first cell and then it has reservation for array length next cells.

When you declare int[79][24] it makes a reservation for 79*24 cells. They go one by one. If the array dimensions are 79x24, you have indexes from 0-78 in the first dimension and 0-23 in the second. The cell at the adress 34,24 is actually one after 34,23 which is 35,0 in the memory.

Let's have an example on array of size 6x4:

```
Your array represented as expected by you with values:
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

Your array with cell adresses (where start is the adress of cell 0,0):
+---+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|   | 0          | 1          | 2          | 3          | 4          | 5          |
+---+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| 0 | start      | start + 1  | start + 2  | start + 3  | start + 4  | start + 5  |
+---+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| 1 | start + 6  | start + 7  | start + 8  | start + 9  | start + 10 | start + 11 |
+---+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| 2 | start + 12 | start + 13 | start + 14 | start + 15 | start + 16 | start + 17 |
+---+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| 3 | start + 18 | start + 19 | start + 20 | start + 21 | start + 22 | start + 23 |
+---+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Your array ranges from 0 to 78 in the first dimension and 0 to 23 in the second dimension. As you are trying to access element that is out of bounds of your array, the behaviour is not defined and anything can happen. This is what might cause your problem. If you want to access index [x][24], you array has to be declared like this: `int myarray[79][25]`.

The "mirroring" apparently occurs, because in the memory, the array elements are allocated next to each other, you can imagine it like a very long line. So right after index for example `[1][23]` is (probably) index `[2][0]`. It's (probably) not guaranteed though, so it's not a good idea to use such a construct. And even if it was defined, it is very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

The memory for the array is contiguous, so although you define say

```
int myarray[79][24];
```

accessing

```
int n = myarray[34][24];
```

is strictly out of bounds.

It might access `myarray[35][0]` but that behaviour is undefined.

Comment: I think it's quite defined as `myarray[34][24]` reserves 34 spaces for 24 cells and then those 24 cells match the allocated space. Might work differently on memory page switch but I don't think so. I'll look for documentation.

Comment: @xenteros sorry, I should have been clearer. `int myarray[79][24]` followed by `int n = myarray[34][24]`  is strictly out of bounds.

Comment: It's defined behavior according to http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf

Comment: @xenteros the clause, please.

Comment: @xenteros that seems good, although another answer saying effectively the same as mine has been upvoted. I found it interesting that in this case, you say that array overflow behaviour is *guaranteed* to be good - except the unmentioned `int n = myarray[78][24];`. BTW I can only upvote you once.

Comment: Do you think that is *good* behaviour? My question is duplicitous.

Comment: I've shown you something you didn't know and was sure is not true. Waste of time.

Comment: I actually did say it will overflow to the next row. You have become obnoxiously arrogant.